# Do the bodies of devas have physical shape and size?

Tags: gods, philosophy

Two possible answers to this question.

First possible answer: The bodies of devas have a physical shape and size.

Second possible answer: The bodies of devas do not have the physical attributes of shape and size.

Third possible answer: The bodies of devas have size but not shape.

Comment: they are kama-rupa. they can take any shape/form they want. although they have a default shape. also, there are ways to distinguish devas from humans - e.g. their feet won't touch earth, they don't cast shadows, they don't sweat, they don't blink etc.

Comment: Are devas essentially connected to these "default shapes", in the same way that humans and animals are essentially connected to our shapes?

Comment: @mar Do they have these default shapes even when they are not appearing to humans?